# Efficiently groupby of dataset whilst retaining additional columns

Tags: python-3.x

I have a large dataset 'df' and i am simply trying to groupby one value 'A', sum another 'B' and then retain the remaining columns 'C' - 'Z' (they will be identical for provided the 'A' is the same. I am currently doing:

```
df = df.groupby(['A',
                 'C',
                 'D',
                 ...
                 'Z'])['B'].sum()
```

This however is taking a long time to execute. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an instance where a database would come in handy.

Put the data into a table

Then just `SELECT A, SUM(B), C GROUP BY A`

A database will be much faster performing aggregate functions than python especially on large datasets.